# Condition number of the product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider two matrices $A$ and $B$ that are non-square in general and may not be full rank. Assuming their shapes are such that the product $A\cdot B$ is well-defined, what is the relationship between their condition numbers? That is, how are $\mathrm{cond}(A)$, $\mathrm{cond}(B)$ and $\mathrm{cond}(A\cdot B)$ related?

Numerical experimentation indicates that $\mathrm{cond}(A\cdot B)<\mathrm{cond}(A)\cdot\mathrm{cond}(B)$...

Comment: I'm assuming that the condition number is the ratio of the largest singular value to the smallest singular value

Comment: Clearly it has to be a $\leq$ and not a $<$. After that, isn't this a consequence of $\|AB\| \leq \|A\| \|B\|$ applied to both $A,B$ and $A^{-1},B^{-1}$? Or am I composing inequalities wrongly?

Comment: something is not quite right. If $A$ is singular, then its condition number is $+\infty$, because $\sigma_{\min}(A)=0$, and the inequalities are trivial.

Comment: @Survit No, the singular values of a matrix are not zero, even if it has a null space.